# Error using fisheye calibration in python binding OpenCV 3.2.0

Tags: python, opencv, camera, camera-calibration, fisheye

System information (version)

```
OpenCV => 3.2
Operating System / Platform => Linux / Ubuntu 15.04
Compiler => Python 3.4.3 (default, Mar 26 2015, 22:03:40) [GCC 4.9.2] on linux
```

When I try the following

```
ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.fisheye.calibrate(object_points, image_points, gray.shape[::-1],None,None)
```

I get the next error

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (objectPoints.type() == CV_32FC3 || objectPoints.type() == CV_64FC3) in calibrate, file /home/angelluis/Descargas/opencv-3.2.0/modules/calib3d/src/fisheye.cpp, line 726
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "calibrate.py", line 59, in <module>
    ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.fisheye.calibrate(object_points, image_points, gray.shape[::-1],None,None)
cv2.error: /home/angelluis/Descargas/opencv-3.2.0/modules/calib3d/src/fisheye.cpp:726: error: (-215) objectPoints.type() == CV_32FC3 || objectPoints.type() == CV_64FC3 in function calibrate
```

I know that this error ocurrs a time ago: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/5534 but I think that it was fixed (https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/6454) in addition, when I try the workaround explained in https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/5534 it doesn't work

How can I run a fisheye calibration from python? (I don't want to use any extra oficial python wrapper)

Comment: I am having the same problem, did you find a solution? I found pyfisheye, but it fails for a different reason (link: https://bitbucket.org/amitibo/pyfisheye)